# Break the automatic page no's and insert a different page no. at specific point in ms-word

Tags: ms-word

I have a word document of 104 pages with all page no displayed as "page 1 of 10" . Now I want to change the page numbers at 95 and display  it as 94a and for page numbers 96 onward as "page 95 of 104" 97 as "page 96 of 104" and so on....
How to do that. I am using MS office 2013.

Comment: This is an end-user question, not a programming one. As such it is off-topic for StackOverflow and should be asked in an appropriate end-user forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Sections** and **Manual Page Breaks** to do this.
There are 4 types of **Section Breaks** - For purposes of this question, I suggest only to use "**Continuous**".  A "Next Page" Section would be more appropriate, but it can become problematic and cast you into Word hell - requiring hours of work to untangle.

**Quick Tutorial**

1. Add several paragraphs of text to a new Word doc. Go to Insert/Footer and choose a page numbering format.
2. Turn on the invisible characters using the icon that looks like a paragraph mark or Cntrl-Shifit-8. You will now see the line breaks and spaces represented with special characters.
3. Place the cursor after a paragraph mark and go to Layout Tab/Page Setup/ Breaks and click "Continuous". You will see that a new "Section Break (Continuous)" has been added. This creates a new Section in the document. We still need a new page.
4. Place the cursor after the Section Break and add a Page Break with Insert/Page Break or Cntrl+Enter.
5. Double click the Footer at the bottom of Page 2 (or whatever is the new page) and notice on the left that the Footer is labelled "Footer -Section2-". On the right there is a "Same as Previous" label. This means the Page Numbering in the Footer is the same as the Previous Section. Opening the Footer also opens the Design Tab. On the Design Tab "Link to Previous" has a dark background, indicating it is active for this Section. Click it to make it inactive. This will remove the "Link to Previous" label from the Footer. You can now edit the Page Number of this section using any of the Page Numbering Tools (or just change it manually). There are a number of Page Numbering tools on the Design Tab. There are also Section Controls in Layout/Page Setup/Layout Tab. Experiment a bit and you'll get the hang of it ;)